# ExpressJS queue requests

Tags: java, typescript, express

I am looking to queue requests to ExpressJs so that only one request is processed on an endpoint at a time. I have found some examples of this: [ExpressJS backend put requests into a queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36083121/expressjs-backend-put-requests-into-a-queue)

It seems though they require a separate function for each endpoint. I am trying to create one function that allows me to pass a queue name, and then stack items in the specified queues.

It is an API listening for requests, and upon receiving one will then execute a request to another online API before relaying the result back to the user through the original express endpoint. Ultimately I will then look to add some very basic caching for each endpoint, just to store a short JSON string for 3 seconds before expiring. That way it returns the cached string within the 3 second limit rather than fetch the data again from online.

Here is as far as I got, I would be curious to hear if there are better ways:

```
//UI request -> check cache -> return response || call request then return response

// Queue items on endpoint
class QueueUnique {
  func;
  q;
  requestCache = [];

  constructor(func) {
    this.q = Promise.resolve();
    this.func = func;
  }

  add(request) {
    // Fetch all cached items related to the current endpoint queue
    const cachedItem = this.requestCache.find(
      (itm) => itm.queueName === request.queueName
    );
    // If the current request is within X seconds of the last successful requesst, return the cache
    // otherwise make a new request
    if (cachedItem && new Date().getTime() - cachedItem.runtime > 3000) {
      console.log(
        "Cache is over 3 seconds old. Doing new request. Queue name: " +
          request.queueName
        // no cahe, forward request:
        //seperate this in to function
        //res.sendResponse = res.send
        // res.send = (body) => {
        //  request.body = body
        //  this.updateCache(request);
        // res.sendResponse(body)
        //}
        //next()
      );
      this.updateCache(request);
    } else if (cachedItem) {
      console.log("Valid cache, return cache");
      // res.send(request.body)
      this.updateCache(request);
    } else {
      console.log("no cache");
      //continue as normal as if no cache
      // no cahe, forward request: Same as first run
      this.addToCache(request);
    }

    // Do I need to use await before setting datetime?

    //then cache

    // Set the current time as a value in the item Array
    request.runtime = new Date().getTime();

    const queuedFunc = this.queue(request);
    queuedFunc();
  }

  addToCache(request) {
    // Add the new item to the permanent cache
    this.requestCache.push(request);
  }

  updateCache(request) {
    // Update the permanent request cache entry
    const arrayIndex = this.requestCache.findIndex(
      (itm) => itm.queueName === request.queueName
    );
    this.requestCache[arrayIndex] = request;
  }

  queue(item) {
    return () => {
      this.q = this.q
        .then(() => this.func(item))
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
      return this.q;
    };
  }
}

const response = (item) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("say", item.payload);
      resolve();
    }, item.delay);
  });
};

const queue = [];
function test(bar, payload) {
  if (!queue[bar]) {
    queue[bar] = new QueueUnique(response);
  }
  queue[bar].add(payload);
  console.log(queue);
  return queue;
}

test("te", {
  queueName: "ping",
  payload: "one",
  delay: 3000,
});

test("te", {
  queueName: "ping",
  payload: "one",
  delay: 3000,
});

test("te", {
  queueName: "ping",
  payload: "one",
  delay: 3000,
});

test("te2", {
  queueName: "ping",
  payload: "two",
  delay: 1000,
});

test("te2", {
  queueName: "ping",
  payload: "two",
  delay: 1000,
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventual implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/balena-labs-research/starter-interface/blob/5cc4965c6caecdad07875942ab209c8092ab6910/expressjs/src/middleware/queueCache.ts), which resolves some bugs in the below.

---

Here is what I have for now. Would be great to hear about improvements or issues. It is converted to Typescript as it is what I ultimately will be using.

```
import queueCache from './middleware/queueCache'

...

app.locals.cacheTimeout = 3000

app.get('/test', queueCache, (_req, res) => {
  res.json({ test: 'test' })
})

app.get('/test1', queueCache, (_req, res) => {
  res.json({ test1: 'test1' })
})
```

queueCache.ts:

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express'

interface requestData {
  queueName?: string
  cachedData?: string
  runtime?: number
}

const cachedItemList = {} as Array<requestData>
const queue = [] as Array<QueueUnique>
const requestCache = [] as Array<requestData>

// Class to queue items and cache results
class QueueUnique {
  func
  q: Promise<unknown>

  constructor(
    func: (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => Promise<unknown>
  ) {
    this.func = func
    this.q = Promise.resolve()
  }

  add(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    // Check if the item is already cached
    if (checkCache(req, res)) {
      return
    }

    // If not cached, add to queue
    const queuedFunc = this.queue(req, res, next)
    queuedFunc()
  }

  queue(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    return () => {
      this.q = this.q
        .then(() => this.func(req, res, next))
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err)
        })
      return this.q
    }
  }
}

const response = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  // Do another check to see if item just finished in queue created a useful cache
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    if (checkCache(req, res)) {
      resolve(true)
      return
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (cachedItemList[0].queueName) {
        // Got this far, and cache exists so it must be older than set time, starting new request.

        // Return response to user
        res.sendResponse = res.json
        res.json = (body) => {
          res.sendResponse(body)
          // Find the current item in the request cache
          const arrayIndex = requestCache?.findIndex(
            (itm) => itm.queueName === req.url
          )
          // Set the time that the request was stored
          requestCache[arrayIndex].runtime = new Date().getTime()
          // Store the body of the response in the cache
          requestCache[arrayIndex].cachedData = body
          return res
        }
      } else {
        // There was no cache

        // Return the response to the caller
        res.sendResponse = res.json
        res.json = (body) => {
          res.sendResponse(body)
          // Only use cache on GET requests. When not GET, this middleware only acts as a queue.
          if (req.method === 'GET') {
            // Check if it is already in cache to avoid duplicates
            // Overcomes an error: https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/4826
            const arrayIndex = requestCache?.findIndex(
              (itm) => itm.queueName === req.url
            )

            if (arrayIndex === -1) {
              requestCache.push({
                cachedData: body, // Add the new item to the permanent cache
                queueName: req.url, // Add the request URL to the item for later reference
                runtime: new Date().getTime() // Add the time the request was made
              })
            }
          }
          return res
        }
      }
      next()
      resolve(true)
    }, 4000)
  })
}

function checkCache(req: Request, res: Response) {
  // Fetch all cached items related to the current endpoint queue, which is named after the endpoint url
  cachedItemList[0] =
    requestCache.find((itm) => itm.queueName === req.url) || {}

  // If the current request is within X seconds of the last successful requesst, return the cached version
  if (
    cachedItemList[0].runtime &&
    new Date().getTime() - cachedItemList[0].runtime <
      req.app.locals.cacheTimeout
  ) {
    // Return the cached item to the user
    res.json(cachedItemList[0].cachedData)
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}

// Create multipule queues, one for each endpoint
function sortQueues(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  // Use the endpoint name to create a queue within the queues array
  if (!queue[req.route.path]) {
    queue[req.route.path] = new QueueUnique(response)
  }
  queue[req.route.path].add(req, res, next)
}

export default sortQueues
```